# VB.NET: running out of memory in System.Drawing.dll

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to teach myself programming, and I'm making an auto-graphing program that submits data to excel and returns a graph. The code is as follows:
Saving the file and exporting it:

' On program activation, establish an I/O stream for the database and load the graph

```
Private Sub Form1_Initialized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated

    '  Open the database
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(DatabasePath + "Database.xlsx")

    '  Set the relevant worksheet
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '  Set the display status of the database
    xlApp.Visible = False

    '  Clear the picture box before exporting to prevent the compiler from accessing a file already in use
    If Not (Graph.Image Is Nothing) Then
        Graph.Image.Dispose()
    End If

    '  Export the graph
    xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(1).chart.Export(FileName:=DatabasePath + ("Graph.gif"), FilterName:="gif")

    '  Load the saved graph image into the userform
    Graph.Image = Image.FromFile(DatabasePath + ("Graph.gif"))

End Sub
```

It won't load the file on form activation though.
The system error comes when I utilize another piece of code, that updates relevant cells in the excel file and changes the data that is graphed. The cells are updated using a textbox change event in the userform:

```
Private Sub Proposed_Dollars_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Proposed_Dollars.TextChanged

    '  Export the data values
    xlWorkSheet.Range("Q10").Value = Proposed_Dollars.Text()

    '  Clear the picture box before exporting to prevent the compiler from accessing a file already in use
    If Not (Graph.Image Is Nothing) Then
        Graph.Image.Dispose()
    End If

    '  Export the graph
    xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(1).chart.Export(FileName:=DatabasePath + ("Graph.gif"), FilterName:="GIF")

    '  Load the saved graph image into the userform
    Graph.Image = Image.FromFile(DatabasePath + ("Graph.gif"))

End Sub
```

Are there any obvious memory leaks that I'm missing that would cause the program to not load the graph into the userform picturebox?
I appreciate any help that is given.

Comment: is `Graph` the name of your picturebox?

Comment: That is a lot a work for each char that is typed into a textbox don't you think?

Comment: How big is the Graph.gif file after export?  Can you open it in Paint or PhotoViewer or something similar?

Comment: yes, sorry, Graph is the name of picturebox.  I am realizing that it is a lot of work for each char typed into a textbox.  I'm going to implement an "update graph button to help alleviate some of the processing requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to save the data back to the excel file, but force it to paint the graph every char is too much. What you should be doing instead is loading some variables from the excel file, allow the user to change the data, which would change the variables, then you use the Paint event to Draw the entire graph and use the variables to display the lines, rectangles, ellipses, etc...  Look into `GDI+` it can do everything you need.